# Facebook Api 3.0 integration with Fragment

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Fragments in android and integrating facebook login with it, to fetch user details.

```
public void postOnfacebook() {
        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true,
                new StatusCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                            Exception exception) {
                        if (session.isOpened()) {
                            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                                    new GraphUserCallback() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                                Response response) {
                                            if (user != null) {
                                                id = user.getId();
                                                name = user.getName();

                                                gender = user
                                                        .getProperty("gender") == null ? "male"
                                                        : user.getProperty(
                                                                "gender")
                                                                .toString();


                                            }

                                    }
                                });
                    }

                }
            });
}
```

I also have following method included in my `fragment` as per documentation

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode,
                resultCode, data);
}
```

I have tried same code in `Activity`, it works there but it doesnot work inside the `Fragment`.
I have included `LoginActivity` inside `AndroidManifest.xml` and `metadate` for `facebookapplicationId` as per documentation.

Can you please suggest where I am going wrong in case of `Fragment`.

Comment: can you please guide me in this.
what was the prob.
i am getting onActivityResult call back in activity instead of caller fragment.

Comment: Well Yashpal, if you found the solution, you should share it, so others could benefit from it. Is'nt that the whole point of SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution, the above code is actually correct, i was doing something else wrong due to which its not working. I corrected that and above code works

Comment: The above code is solution Veeru, you must have read my answer before, placing comment

Comment: My apologies - I did'nt see which part of the code you have modified/updated to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, facebook sdk does not support fragments. 
So onActivityForResult will not be triggered, this has to be moved into the fragments Parent
Parent FragmentActivity should have the following code; This updates the session in the fragment as well and you can handle the session in your fragment.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        System.out.println("OnActivityResult fragment Parent");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                resultCode, data);
    }
```

in the fragment add something similar to the following. Use getActivity() to get the fragment. session.isOpened() will trigger automatically when parentFragmentActivity's onActivityResult is executed.

```
btnFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
                            Exception exception) {
                        System.out.println("Session :"+session.getState());
                        if (session.isOpened()) {
                            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                                    new GraphUserCallback() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                                Response response) {
                                            if (user != null) {
                                                System.out.println("User ID "+user.getId());
                                                System.out.println("User Name "+user.getFirstName()+" "+user.getLastName());;
                                                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                                      if (user != null) {
                                                          System.out.println(user.getName());
                                                          System.out.println("facebook user id" + user.getId());
                                                         System.out.println(user.asMap().get("email").toString());
                                                         // Session.OpenRequest open = new Session.OpenRequest(Login)
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                  });
                                            }

                                    }
                                });
                    }

                }
            });
    }
});
```